# UE4 -ApplyDamage to specific Actor

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have an issue I've been trying to fix for about a week now, but for the life of me cannot figure it out.

I have a function
`DamageOnOverlap(AActor* HitActor, AActor* OtherActor`
which deals damage on overlap. Within that function, I have the following function
`UGameplayStatics::ApplyDamage(OtherActor, 25.0f, GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController(), this, UDamageType::StaticClass());`
which deals damage to the overlapped actor. These two functions are in my
ZombieBasic.cpp
so then they overlap each other, they take damage and Destroy when their health is 0.
Is there a way to do a check or something so they're unable to cause damage to themselves?

I have done the following check

```
if(OtherActor == mainCharacter)
{
    UGameplayStatics::ApplyDamage(OtherActor, 20.f, GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController(), this, UDamageType::StaticClass());
}
```

But either the they all still take damage or no damage is applied at all.
`OtherActor` will call `AMainCharacter` (`AMainCharacter* mainCharacter` is defined in the header file for ref).

So, I'm basically trying to stop ApplyDamage OR DamageOnOverlap from damaging other actors of the same type, which in this case, stop `AZombieBasic` from damaging another `ABasicZombie`.

Sorry if this is a rubbish explanation.

Answer (score 0):

With some investigation, I have managed to fix the problem.

**TL;DR**
I added an Actor Tag to the mainCharacter class and did a check in ZombieBasic to see if an actor has the specified tag.

**Read if you're interested**

Adding an Actor tag to 'AMainCharacter' within the Blueprint Class under the Actor section and adding a new tag of Player. In ZombieBasic.cpp, in the `DamageOnOverlap` function I did a basic check of

```
if(OtherActor->ActorHasTag("Player")
{
   // Deal Damage
}
```

Now when BP_BasicZombie overlap with themselves they no longer deal damage to themselves.